# How am I getting a linker error: Unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, linker, external, symbols

This is in a Windows Console application, so I have no idea how this is happening at all.

```
#include "Library.h"

//poglathon.cpp
//starting region


bool Poglathon(std::vector<std::string>& text,Player *player){
    using namespace std;
    cout << "You see a town to one side and a path leading to a dark, murky forest in the other side." << endl;
    int chosen = player->giveOptions(2,"Town","Path","","","");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Further to Let_Me_Be's question: Pig Head, please show us the exact linker error message.

Comment: (keep clicking comment-up accidentally) bool __cdecl - is that the symbol?

Comment: Here's the entire message: `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl Poglathon(class std::vector<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > &,class Player)" (?Poglathon@@YA_NAAV?$vector@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@std@@VPlayer@@@Z) referenced in function _main`

Comment: `Poglathon` is the symbol. Please provide the definition, the declaration and the call statement of Poglathon.

Comment: `Poglathon(vec, 0); // bang, you're dead` Check for null (a valid pointer value!) or use a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your declaration in the header file looks like this:

```
bool Poglathon(std::vector<std::string>& text,Player player);
```

Your attempt to define in the cpp file looks like this:

```
bool Poglathon(std::vector<std::string>& text,Player * player);
```

Change the declaration to take a `Player *` instead of a `Player`

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the problem is that the declaration of the function (inside your header files) is like this:

```
bool Poglathon(std::vector<std::string>& text,Player player);
```

But you defined it like this:

```
bool Poglathon(std::vector<std::string>& text,Player *player)
```

Decide what you want and be consistent.

Comment: Whoops, I forgot about that declaration.